# VirtualStringTree, changing the row background color

Tags: delphi, tvirtualstringtree

I have got some of the latest version of the VirtualTreeView and try to
change the background color of the whole row of `TVirtualStringTree` both in selected and in non-selected states (`toFullRowSelect` is included somewhere). There is a lot of similar questions with different answers but none seems to fit well. In all of them you just write a handler that includes the code snippet like this:

```
  TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := SomeColor;
  TargetCanvas.FillRect(SomeRect);
```

But it's not that simple as I thought:

1. `OnBeforeCellPaint` handler works well only if the row is not
   selected
2. `OnDrawText` handler works in both states but the entire
   row looks divided by spaces between cells
3. `OnBeforeItemErased` affects the whole row but again if it is not in selected state
4. The painting in some other handlers either are repainted later automatically or require fully manual drawing which looks excessive for a simple task.

So I failed to find an easy way.

I added the additional conditions:

1. The row must stay in selected state cause the tree could be in MultiSelected mode (`toMultiSelect` is included).
2. The colors of selected and unselected states of the row may differ as well as different selected rows may have different colors too.

The best I could create is to write a handler on `OnDrawTexr` event:
[image: tree]

This tree is produced by an array of records (oversimplified):

```
type
  TJob=record
    Running:Boolean;// the job is stopped or running
    MaxDuration:integer;//0 - infinite, or seconds
    Start:TDateTime;//The job start time
  end;
```

- if the job is stopped its row should behave in the default treeview
  way.
- If the job is running and infinite it should be colored e.g. as
  green, if selected - as thick green
- If the job is running and have
  limited duration its row should have a transitioned color between
  green and red that changes constantly while meeting its deadline. If
  selected the color should be brighter.

Comment: It sounds like you have an answer to your question, except that you feel it is not "easy enough"... Perhaps you can point to the other question you are referring to? Personally I do custom row colors in OnAfterCellPaint event and use the check `if vsSelected in Node.States then`, but then have to also draw the text manually using DrawText api.

Comment: Nope, I don't, I have just made an interim solution with the handler on `OnDrawText` event, it looks awful but the best I could have done

Comment: A few facts are still missing: 1) If you may want to have different colors (for normal state, selected state etc.) per node, where are you going to store those? From where, are the colors to be fetched. 2) you have presented the result of your own effort, but not the code with which you arrived at that result. Please add that also. 3) Your code will show it, but anyway: why is the Name field continuing into the Operator field, or are these two just painted without space in between?

Comment: One more detail: Which version of `Virtual Trees` do you have? It is meaningless to say "*some of the latest version*" Look in Changes.txt for the exact version.

Comment: @Tom I am using the version downloaded from the GitHub a month ago, all source files are of 10/02/2022,  I wasn't able to locate the exact version number, I guess its some around 7.6. As per the way that produces the tree I will elaborate it more clearly if it helps in a few minutes.

Comment: You have rather long "minutes". I still don't see any response to my points 2) and 3). I'm kind of losing interest very soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OnBeforeCellPaint` for non selected row, use `Colors.FocusedSelectionColor` property for selected row..

Comment: I corrected the question cause I'd like to make the color to be row based not the tree based, also the `Colors` property is in `Private` section now.

Answer (score 0):

in VirtualTrees, if node select, it must draw..
in `VirtualTrees.pas` `line 25974`

```
          if vsSelected in Node.States then
          begin
             if Focused or (toPopupMode in FOptions.FPaintOptions) then
             begin
                Brush.Color := FColors.FocusedSelectionColor;
                Pen.Color := FColors.FocusedSelectionBorderColor;
              end
              else
              begin
                Brush.Color := FColors.UnfocusedSelectionColor;
                Pen.Color := FColors.UnfocusedSelectionBorderColor;
              end;
          ....
          end
```

you can delete it:

```
              //Brush.Color := FColors.FocusedSelectionColor;
              //Pen.Color := FColors.FocusedSelectionBorderColor;
```

also you can do it on `OnBeforeCellPaint` and change node to **not select**:

```
  TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $00776655;
  TargetCanvas.FillRect(CellRect);
  Exclude(Node.States, vsSelected);
```

it will like follow:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't like the idea of changing the external sources without clear reasons to do so, there is a lot of trees and most of them should have the default behavior.  Also I added two more conditions to the question.